# Calling a JS function in Blazor Server on production environment causes reconnect

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to open a link in a new tab in Blazor server and am using js interop:

```
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", url, "blank");
```

This works on my local machine with the build running using dotnet watch run, but when I deploy it to the server I get a "Attempting to reconnect..." for a few seconds and the JS doesn't run.

Does anyone know what's happening and how I can fix this? Thanks.

EDIT1: Some additional context - this code is being called by ChartJS's OnClick callback for a linechart, which probably means that JS is on the other end of that. I have also found that using NavigationManager.NavigateTo within that method callback causes the same issue.

Comment: Question 1: it sounds like the URL you are opening is also served by your Blazor application - is that correct? Question 2: Which browser tab shows the reconnecting message - the original or the new one? Question 3: Are there any errors in the browser dev tools console?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Question 1: yes. Question 2: the original one, there is no new one since it doesn't open. Question 3 - there is one error, specifically this one: "2021-07-15T11:40:31.394Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'.". It is also worth noting that the same problem occurs when calling any JS function from .NET. I just tried a simple function with an alert() call and the same happens.

Comment: I've also added additional context as an edit to my post, so see that as well please.

Answer (score 0):

You were **missing an underscore** in your third parameter:

```
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", url, "_blank");
```

It is `_blank` instead of `blank`. Your browser is trying to look for a `blank` frame, doesn't find it and reloads the whole page.